How to solve the pip install error on Kaggle/Colab
I am trying to install some libraries in my code but it always show this error.
!pip install optuna-integration


WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7944200bc370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/optuna-integration/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7944200bc670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/optuna-integration/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7944200bc910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/optuna-integration/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7944200bcac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/optuna-integration/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7944200bcc70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/optuna-integration/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optuna-integration (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for optuna-integration

Error in pip installation
I already check if I have any VPN, DNS (that is not 8.8.8.8), proxy active and this is not the situation.

Seems like a network problem
